# Restarting a Linux server from a Windows batch file

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

I've been working on a problem that I was hoping someone with more experience could weigh in on. I've recently started learning about Windows .bat files, and I've been thinking about real-world applications for cross-OS usage.

**Here's the setup:**

*There is a Linux core server configured to run a particular program full-time, but the program occasionally "bugs out" (**effecting users without creating an error**), and the best way to fix the issue is by restarting the server. The property does not want the server to go down unless necessary, so scheduled reboots are not permitted. In addition, because the server is configured specifically for this program, no additional applications or services could be installed without causing additional problems on the server.*

*The server requires admin credentials for logging on, but all of the users use Windows 10 Pro computers, and are unfamiliar with Linux, so they would not be able to resolve the issue by themselves, and would be required to contact a third-party.
As such, you have been asked to create a .bat file that could be put onto the Windows machine that could be run by the staff that would restart the server without having any additional input from the users (**File security is not a factor. Usernames, Passwords, and user input can be included in the .bat file**).*

##**Additional Notes:**##

From what I have gathered while looking into this previously, it looks like the Windows .bat file would initiate an ssh session with the Linux server, then enter in the username, then password, and issue the "sudo reboot" command.
Alternatively, it seems like the ssh could be used to run an executable .sh file on the Linux server to do the same thing.
I've found similar examples online, but all of them seem to use additionally downloaded programs or services to do them.

How would you do it?

Edit: The biggest hiccup I have seen so far is when the connection asks for a password. It doesn't seem to accept it from the .bat file.
My current attempt at the .bat file looks like:

```
ssh -t [user]@[ip_address]
SLEEP 10
@echo [password]
@echo sudo reboot
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please add this information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that is a clumsy solution to the issue.

Best option to the problem would be to fix the application so that it doesn't become unresponsive.

If that is not possible, then you should set up the Linux system to automatically restart services if they become unresponsive.

Next best option is to set up automatic rebooting of the server if certain services are not up. This is needed if you don't exactly know which services crash.

The last option is what you are planning: forcing end-users to react if service goes down.

Please consider other options before pursuing with your plan.

Comment: The issue with your recommendation is that the application and services **do not crash**. Services do not go down in the live environment, and are still listed as running without errors or warnings. The only indication that we have had has been when end users mention that there are issues.

Comment: The approach is still the same, you should fix the root cause that causes whatever issue you are having. Adding a band-aid only creates an even more complex system which is hard to maintain in the long run. Mikael H wrote a good suggestion on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The part `In addition, because the server is configured specifically for this program, no additional applications or services could be installed without causing additional problems on the server.` is NOT an example of evidence-based operational practices.

Given that, and following up on @Tero Kilkanen's answer:
There's going to be some way of identifying that the service has stopped doing what it should. Set up monitoring locally on the server, which alerts your Ops team when that happens. That's the first step. Keep a log of these events so you can present a business case for spending money on fixing the underlying issue.

Second, use the monitor to drive an automated restart of the service, or in the worst case a reboot of the entire server - though again, that would most probably not be necessary if you actually understand what goes wrong, as you should.

If you *really* need to do it the bad way, I would suggest you look up the openssh (on the client) and sudoers (on the server) documentation (if we're talking modern Windows 10 versions with the openssh client installed). You will want to create a limited access account on the server with passwordless sudo rights *only* to execute the `/usr/sbin/reboot` command (path may vary across distributions). You simplify authentication by making it key based (`-i filename` on the client), and you can include the command to run (specifically the reboot command) directly as an argument to the ssh client.